# How do you alter the aspects of fields in a matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

We were given an assignment in class to where we would create a program to calculate 9 values and store them in a 3x3 matrix. However, the teacher stressed the disuse of tabbing to align the objects in the matrix.

The matrix is supposed to look something like:

```
[0.0000,  0.9211, -0.3894,
 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]
```

(The first [ should be at beginning of line)

"For each field printed, the field width should be 8 (I don't understand what he means by this), and the output should use the fixed manipulator." was the instruction.

The teacher didn't go over arrays yet so I'm assuming we're supposed to just use cout, but how exactly would I make it work here in terms of spacing? Would I just put 8 spaces in cout << "insert 8 spaces here" << "0.0000" or?

Comment: have a look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf . Your `cout` is just an output stream. These are the format modifiers for those.

Answer (score 1):

The example you have shown has (most of) the floating point numbers in a field of width 8 - each number is exactly 8 characters wide (although the first character is always a space, and the second character is either a space or a minus sign).

The exception is that the first column appears to be in field of width six, and alignment will break if you print a number which is less than zero or greater-equal 10.

Manipulators are objects which can be output to a stream (like `cout`), and which change the formatting of that stream.

For details of the `fixed` manipulator, see:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

You will probably need to use the `setw` manipulator too:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: Yeah those were the two specific ones I needed! Managed to figure it out. cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(8) << setfill(' ') and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution (but written in seconds):

use **setw()** from **iomanip**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define MTXDIM  3

float mtx[MTXDIM][MTXDIM]=
    {
        {0.0000, 0.9211, -0.3894},
        {0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000},
        {0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000}
    };

int main() 
{
    cout<<"[";
    for(int i=0;i<MTXDIM;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<MTXDIM;j++)
        {
            cout << fixed << (!(i+j) ? setw(7) : setw(8)) << right << setprecision(4) << mtx[i][j];
            if(i==MTXDIM-1 && j==MTXDIM-1) cout<<"]";
            else cout<<",";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[ 0.0000,  0.9211, -0.3894,
  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000]
```